# Processing Symfony Bundle Resources automatically

Tags: php, xml, symfony, xsd

I'm developing a XML Validation service that uses multiple XML Schema files for validation of XML files in my application. XML Schema files use imports heavily. For that reason I need a service, that would associate namespaces to their schema definitions (file locations).

Each XML namespace is defined in separate XSD.

I know I could use *schemaLocation* attributes to connect schemas with their files, but that would require using lots of relative paths and wouldn't work well with arbitrary project structures:

```
<-- schema.xsd -->
<xsd:import namespace="urn.my.namespace" schemaLocation="..."/>

<-- actual.xml -->
<root xmlns="urn.my.namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn.my.namespace schema.xsd">
</root>
```

I would like to create a service that walks throughout bundles, discovers xsd files and registers their namespace - file location association into some kind of registry that would
be available for other XML services.

My Symfony project has the following structure:

```
AbcBundle/
    Resources/config/services.xml
    Resources/xsd/
        schema.xsd
        ns1.xsd
        ns2.xsd
        ...
    AbcBundle.php
XyzBundle/
    [same structre]
```

Planned usage:

```
$nsLocator = $container->get('xml.ns_locator');
$nsLocator->getNamespaceMap();
/* returns array(
    'urn:my:ns1' => '/realpath/to/ns1.xsd',
    'urn:my:ns2' => '/otherpath/to/ns2.xsd',
*/
```

The *$nsLocator* should build that map automatically from Bundle/Resources/xsd/ directories.
I like the way that Symfony registers Bundle/Command or Bundle/Controller with its stack.

I was thinking of some kind of event listener that would hook into Kernel and once all Bundles are registered it would scan all XSDs and create a map. If done this way, It would require a caching so it doesn't rescan all the files every time a new request or a command is executed.

How do I build that component and hook it into kernel? Where is the correct connection point for this component? Is it generally a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a compiler pass which would be run while the container is being built (after the main pass).

During your pass, get list of bundles and iterate through them to create a list of xsd files. Finally, pass the list to your service.

To get list of bundles:

```
$container->getParameter('kernel.bundles')
```

Read more:

- [How to work with compiler passes](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html)
- [Creating compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html#create-a-compilerpass)
- [Compiling the container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html)
- [Container building workflow](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/workflow.html)